# an issue in preview an image gallery carousel in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I have create an image gallery with angular carousel. When i click on the particular image from the thumbnail gallery(for example if i select 4th image) the preview or popup view show the first image from the image gallery. but it has to display the particular selected image(e.g 4th image) from the gallery, the popup view have to show the selected image.
Thanks in advance.

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Carousel</title>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/angular-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/example-fixed-layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/ladda-themeless.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body ng-app="app" data-flow-prevent-drop data-flow-drag-enter="dropClass='drag-over'" data-flow-drag-leave="dropClass=''">

    <!-- Modal -->
    <h3>Image Upload</h3>
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image Preview</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <carousel interval="myInterval">
                            <slide ng-repeat="file in images">
                                <div data-flow-init>

                                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                    <img data-flow-img="file" class="carousel-inner" data-toggle="modal" style="width:500px;height:400px;">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><b>Picture {{$index+1}} of {{images.length}}</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </slide>
                        </carousel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div data-flow-init data-flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()" data-flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]">
                <div class="drop" data-flow-drop ng-class="dropClass">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" data-flow-btn><span class="ladda-label">Upload Image</span></span>
                </div>

                <br />
                <div style="border: solid gray 1px; width: 220px; height: 195px; cursor: pointer;">
                    <carousel interval="myInterval">
                        <slide active="slide.active" ng-repeat="file in $flow.files">
                            <div>
                                <img data-flow-img="file" class="carousel-inner" data-toggle="modal" data-max-size="10kb" data-ng-click="openLargeImage($flow.files,$index)" style=" width:220px;height:165px;">
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:220px; height:25px;">
                                <span style="position:absolute; width:220px; height:25px;right:50px;"> <b>Picture: {{$index+1}} of {{$flow.files.length}}</b></span>
                                <span style="position:absolute;width:220px; height:25px;left:80px"> <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="file.cancel()"> Remove </a></span>
                            </div>
                        </slide>
                    </carousel>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/flow.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fusty-flow.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fusty-flow-factory.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ng-flow.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/showImageLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ladda.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'flow']);
        app.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
            flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
                target: '',
                permanentErrors: [500, 501],
                maxChunkRetries: 1,
                chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
                simultaneousUploads: 1
            };
            flowFactoryProvider.on('fileAdded', function (file, event) {
                console.log(file, event);
            });

            flowFactoryProvider.on('catchAll', function (event) {
                console.log('catchAll', arguments);
            });

            // Can be used with different implementations of Flow.js
            flowFactoryProvider.factory = fustyFlowFactory;
        }]);

        app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {


            $scope.$on('test', function (event, result) {
                alert(result);
                event.preventDefault();//prevent file from uploading
            });

            $scope.up = function () {

            };

            $scope.openLargeImage = function (files, index) {
                $scope.images = files;
                $scope.index = index;
                $('#myModal').modal($scope)
            };

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code is working fine but i have above mentioned issue

Comment: why do you have 2 carousel ? why do you send $scope to your modal ?

Comment: i have 2 carousel bcoz in preview also i have to show the images using  carousel.

Comment: In preview, should the next/previous button still works as well as auto-cycling functionality?

Comment: its auto-cycling functionality

Comment: So you want to show the same carousel but larger in the preview, and now the problem you encounter is that the opened preview is not in sync with the one outside?

Comment: yes.. you are right.can u pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modal is just use to display img, do it like this

```
data-ng-click="openLargeImage(file)"
```

in your JS

```
$scope.openLargeImage = function (file) {
          $scope.img = file.image;
          $('#myModal').modal();
        };
```

in your modal

```
<img ng-src="{{img}}" />
```

it's not tested but that's the easiest way to do it

Comment: In the model i need to pass the all the images from the thumbnail gallery and have to display the particular selected image (which i click in the thumbnail) in the expanded carousel..

Comment: so you stock the url of the "no-thumbnail" image, and you replace $scope.img = file.image; by $scope.img = file.imageLarge;